# Make layout invisible Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have linear layout.

I want it invisible until text will add into text fields.

Code

```
private void Display (){
        LinearLayout display2 = FindViewById<LinearLayout> (Resource.Id.linearLayout12);        
        //LinearLayout display = FindViewById<LinearLayout> (Resource.Id.linearLayout13);           
        TextView productname = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.posttittle);
        TextView price = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.price);
        TextView weight = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.weight);

        productname.Text = Intent.GetStringExtra("title");

        price.Text = Intent.GetStringExtra("price");
        weight.Text = Intent.GetStringExtra("weight");
        display2.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        productname.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        price.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        weight.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
    }
```

My axml

```html
 <ScrollView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="390.3dp"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:background="@drawable/middle1">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout12"
            android:visibility = "gone">
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="147.6dp"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout13">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:minWidth="25px"
                    android:minHeight="25px"
                    android:layout_width="184.9dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout15">
                    <TextView
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:layout_width="181.9dp"
                        android:layout_height="63.3dp"
                        android:id="@+id/posttittle"
                        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="7.7dp"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:visibility="gone" />
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:minWidth="25px"
                        android:minHeight="25px"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="93.8dp"
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayout16">
                        <TextView
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="48.7dp"
                            android:id="@+id/price"
                            android:layout_marginTop="39.8dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5.5dp"
                            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                            android:visibility="gone" />
                        <TextView
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:layout_width="58.8dp"
                            android:layout_height="53.3dp"
                            android:id="@+id/weight"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="21.5dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="41.9dp"
                            android:textColor="#faaf56"
                            android:paddingTop="7dp"
                            android:visibility="gone" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
             <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:minWidth="25px"
                android:minHeight="25px"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout23"
                android:background="#99999999" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

But when I launch activity I see linearlayout.

Maybe it happens because I call Display() in OnCreate?

How I can do that linear layout stay "gone" until Display() runs?

Comment: yourView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

Comment: this is java code. I use c#.

I set it invisible in axml.

I need it visible when Display() runs

@SarthakMittal

Comment: show your xml please..

Comment: if you do not call "Display()" at all, is the Layout(display2) visible or invisible?

Comment: If I don't call it visible@0X0nosugar

Comment: I comment Display()
and it invisible@0X0nosugar

Comment: then like you said, you call "Display()" in "onCreate()", and as soon as it gets executed (= when launching the activity), the Layout is visible. Do you want to delay the layout showing on screen?

Comment: Yes. I want to show it only when     productname.Text = Intent.GetStringExtra("title"); runs. @0X0nosugar

Comment: this should be the case, **if** 'Intent.GetStringExtra("title")' returns the expected value

Comment: i tried somethin like this. if (productname.Text == Intent.GetStringExtra ("title")) {
    display2.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
   }

but it doesn't works@0X0nosugar

Comment: All okay, I incorrectly write if/else.

Comment: really "all okay"? - Then maybe you'd like to write down your solution as an answer. (I can't, I'm from the Java side ;-) and while there are lots of similarities, I still don't know C# or xamarin well enough )

Answer (score 0):

```
display2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
display2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

will make your linearlayout invisible.

```
    display2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Will make it appear.

Comment: nope. look I already set it invisible in axml file.

I want it visible when Display() runs.

But it visible when I launch activity

Comment: voting this down because a Java solution to a C#/ xamarin question makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

That's the answer

```
    private void Display (){
        LinearLayout display2 = FindViewById<LinearLayout> (Resource.Id.linearLayout12);        
        //LinearLayout display = FindViewById<LinearLayout> (Resource.Id.linearLayout13);           
        TextView productname = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.posttittle);
        TextView price = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.price);
        TextView weight = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.weight);


        productname.Text = Intent.GetStringExtra ("title");

        if (productname.Text == Intent.GetStringExtra ("title")) {
            display2.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        } 
        else {
            display2.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        }


        price.Text = Intent.GetStringExtra("price");
        weight.Text = Intent.GetStringExtra("weight");
        //display2.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        productname.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        price.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        weight.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
    }
```